# cron job command for automysqlbackup.sh file

Tags: cron

I just installed Automysqlbackup.sh to my server. I wonder what cron job command should be to run it everyday ?

```
Note: i will set cron job from Cpanel

Path to script is: /home/username/automysqlbackup.sh
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0 0 * * *  /home/username/automysqlbackup.sh
```

This will run the job every night at midnight.

Here's what that job would look like in cpanel:

[image: cPanel cron configuration]

Comment: didnt work. it works when i execute it from SSH but with cron it didnt work :(

Comment: by the way, i set cron from CPANEL, not from SSH

Comment: I've edited my answer with a screenshot from cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server, automysqlbackup.sh included a cronjob. This is what it looks like. It's very simple.

```
$ cat /etc/cron.daily/automysqlbackup
#!/bin/sh
test -x /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup && /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup
```

So, automysqlbackup runs as part of the Daily cronjobs. The schedule for the daily cronjobs can be seen in `/etc/crontab`.